# Flink job gives an error "A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply."

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I have a flink project which reads files from s3 path

```
Path[] paths = s3BucketInfoList.stream().map(appendBucketNameAndPath()).toArray(Path[]::new);
FileSource<String> fileSource = FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(new TextLineInputFormat(), paths).build();
return execEnv.fromSource(fileSource, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "file-input");
```

when I run this code it fails with below exception if its a huge amount of files, The same code is working fine when it runs with less number of files.

```
2023-03-29 13:47:58,354 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Starting execution of job 'project-flink' (000000006e6b13320000000000000000) under job master id b243c2a5cb802073447c8ce200d3441d.
2023-03-29 13:47:58,357 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinator [] - Starting split enumerator for source Source: parse-input.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ByteBufferUtil (file:/tmp/flink-rpc-akka_c077d9de-ac44-4cd4-b63b-38483c61102a.jar) to method java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.cleaner()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ByteBufferUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2023-03-29 13:48:57,882 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Registering TaskManager with ResourceID 1xx.1xx.xx.xxx:xxxx-fc14fd (akka.tcp://flink@1xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/user/rpc/taskmanager_0) at ResourceManager
2023-03-29 13:48:57,886 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Registering TaskManager with ResourceID 1xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx-23dfb8 (akka.tcp://flink@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/user/rpc/taskmanager_0) at ResourceManager
2023-03-29 13:48:57,887 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Registering TaskManager with ResourceID 1xx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx-4fdc8e (akka.tcp://flink@xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx/user/rpc/taskmanager_0) at ResourceManager
2023-03-29 13:48:57,889 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Registering TaskManager with ResourceID 1xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx-cae189 (akka.tcp://flink@1xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/user/rpc/taskmanager_0) at ResourceManager
2023-03-29 13:56:18,441 [ERROR] com.flink.project [] - Exception 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Invocation of [LocalRpcInvocation(RestfulGateway.requestJobStatus(JobID, Time))] at recipient [akka.tcp://flink@project-flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/dispatcher_1] timed out. This is usually caused by: 1) Akka failed sending the message silently, due to problems like oversized payload or serialization failures. In that case, you should find detailed error information in the logs. 2) The recipient needs more time for responding, due to problems like slow machines or network jitters. In that case, you can try to increase akka.ask.timeout.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.getJobExecutionResult(StreamContextEnvironment.java:191) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:148) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2049) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.flink.project.methodname(ClassName.java:94) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.flink.project.main(ClassName.java:66) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:98) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:301) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.lambda$runApplicationAsync$2(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:254) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter.java:171) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$withContextClassLoader$0(ClassLoadingUtils.java:41) ~[?:?]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49) ~[?:?]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Invocation of [LocalRpcInvocation(RestfulGateway.requestJobStatus(JobID, Time))] at recipient [akka.tcp://flink@project-flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/dispatcher_1] timed out. This is usually caused by: 1) Akka failed sending the message silently, due to problems like oversized payload or serialization failures. In that case, you should find detailed error information in the logs. 2) The recipient needs more time for responding, due to problems like slow machines or network jitters. In that case, you can try to increase akka.ask.timeout.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.$Proxy49.requestJobStatus(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.JobStatusPollingUtils.lambda$getJobResult$0(JobStatusPollingUtils.java:57) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.JobStatusPollingUtils.pollJobResultAsync(JobStatusPollingUtils.java:87) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.JobStatusPollingUtils.lambda$null$3(JobStatusPollingUtils.java:107) ~[job.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/rpc/dispatcher_1#-491464203]] after [500000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalFencedMessage]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
2023-03-29 13:56:18,443 [INFO] com.flink.project           [] - Total Time Taken by Dispute Log Pipeline [500345]
2023-03-29 14:01:07,050 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Closing TaskExecutor connection xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx-4fdc8e because: The TaskExecutor is shutting down.
2023-03-29 14:01:07,052 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Closing TaskExecutor connection xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx-33c819 because: The TaskExecutor is shutting down.
2023-03-29 14:01:07,053 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Closing TaskExecutor connection xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx-16a88f because: The TaskExecutor is shutting down.
2023-03-29 14:01:07,128 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Closing TaskExecutor connection xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxx-523c7b because: The TaskExecutor is shutting down.
2023-03-29 14:01:07,192 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM. Shutting down as requested.
2023-03-29 14:01:07,193 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Shutting StandaloneApplicationClusterEntryPoint down with application status UNKNOWN. Diagnostics Cluster entrypoint has been closed externally..
```

Task managers doesn't have any error, it shows
"Successful registration at resource manager"
And flink dashboard not even showing running jobs, seems like job is not even starts reading.

There is a flink issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11143

I can see there they are suggesting

"Job submission timeout is caused by listing too many files in S3
during env.readFile call to create input DataSet."

And the method(FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(...)) I used is an alternative for readTextFile(), So how I'm supposed to handle this and make it run successfully?

Is this only the reason or anything else? Because I tried increasing client timeout, akka timeout etc. but that is not helping. Any other ways?